# JQuery HTTPRequest to show all files in a folder

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hey guys I really didnt know why it doenst work... Offline on my Computer all is fine and online on the Server I´ve this ERROR all the time:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
>       jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 GET http://portfolio.cookie-soft.de/pages/ 404 (Not Found)
>       script.js:35 Status: error
>       script.js:36 Error: Not Found

My script:

```
//Load pages
$.ajax({
    url: "pages/",
    async:false,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find("td > a").each(function(i) {
            if (i > 0)
                src[i] = $(this).attr("href");
        });
        src.shift();
        $.each(src, function(index, val) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "pages/" + val,
                dataType: "text",
                async: false,
                success : function (data) {
                    $('#slider').append(data);
                }
            });
            ele += 1;
        });
        if (ele==src.length)
            $load = true;
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log("Status: " + textStatus); 
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

Comment: ``async:false,`` try setting this to true?

Comment: It's all in the error message, just remove async: false - it's terrible approach actually. Because while you getting data from the server all your js is just waiting when you get the response.

Comment: First job is to remove `async: false` to get rid of the console waring. It's both bad practice and bad for the UI. However the main issue you have is that the `pages/` endpoint you're calling is not being found. Check the routing.

Comment: It's telling you that the `pages` script isn't in the same folder as the page that's running the script.

Comment: Hey and thank u for that fast! I need `async: false` for the rest of the script and i allready tryied it... I also tryied to change the url in the full path